# Gson - Convert from json string to list of objects

Tags: java, gson

I have a JSON string of the format:

```
resp = '{"result": [{x: 1, y:2}, {x:3, y:4}]}'
```

I want to convert the data from "result" key into list of objects. Something like:

```
List<MyCustomObj> data = new Gson()
        .fromJson(resp, new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyCustomObj>>(){}.getType());
```

Is there a way to specify in above statement to fetch from the key "result"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a DTO that describes the structure of JSON, like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Response {
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class MyCustomObject {
        private int x;
        private int y;
    }
    private List<MyCustomObject> result;
}
```

Then it is just:

```
Response resp = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
List<MyCustomObject> result = resp.getResult();
```

It might be a good idea to keep the JSON format and the data structure in sync instead of some special parsing. There might not be any performance boost gained.